# how to get 2 digits after decimal point in tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I am having problem to format digits in my select column.I used FORMAT but it doesn't work.
Here is my column:

```
sum(cast(datediff(second, IEC.CREATE_DATE, IEC.STATUS_DATE) as float) / 60) TotalSentMinutes
```

I used this:

```
FORMAT(sum(cast(datediff(second, IEC.CREATE_DATE, IEC.STATUS_DATE) as float) / 60),2) TotalSentMinutes
```

ERROR:

> 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I format this calculation?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @i FLOAT = 6.677756

SELECT 
      ROUND(@i, 2)
    , FORMAT(@i, 'N2')
    , CAST(@i AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    , SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)), 1), PATINDEX('%.%', CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10))) - 1, 2)
    , FLOOR((@i - FLOOR(@i)) * 100)
```

Output:

```
----------------------
6,68
6.68
6.68
67
67
```

Comment: FORMAT function is available from version 2012 onwards

Comment: This does not work for negative numbers. You should use `ROUND` instead of `FLOOR` to properly truncate the number, like this: `ROUND((@i - ROUND(@i, 0, 1)) * 100, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 16):

You could cast it to DECIMAL and specify the scale to be 2 digits

[decimal and numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

So, something like

```
DECLARE @i AS FLOAT = 2
SELECT @i / 3
SELECT CAST(@i / 3 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

### [SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13203)

I would however recomend that this be done in the UI/Report layer, as this will cuase loss of precision.

**Formatting (in my opinion) should happen on the UI/Report/Display level.**

Comment: Thank you for still providing the answer BUT ALSO the recommendation to do it in another layer.

Comment: what is 18 mean in DECIMAL(18,2)  ?

Comment: @HahaTTpro The 18 in DECIMAL(18,2) means you can have a decimal number with a maximal total precision of 18 digits. 2 of them after the decimal point and 16 before. The largest possible number would thus be (9999999999999999.99).

Answer (score 5):

Try cast result to numeric

```
CAST(sum(cast(datediff(second, IEC.CREATE_DATE, IEC.STATUS_DATE) as float) / 60)
    AS numeric(10,2)) TotalSentMinutes
```

> Input

1 
2 
3

> Output

1.00 
2.00 
3.00

Answer (score 2):

Your format syntax is wrong actual syntax is

```
 FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

Please follow this link it helps you

[Click here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

So, something like

```
DECLARE @i AS FLOAT = 2
SELECT @i / 3
SELECT CAST(@i / 3 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

I would however recomend that this be done in the UI/Report layer, as this will cuase loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @i AS FLOAT = 2
SELECT @i / 3
SELECT cast(@i / cast(3 AS DECIMAL(18,2))as decimal (18,2))

Both factor and result requires casting to be considered as decimals.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CAST(12.0910239123 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
```

Answer (score -2):

Assume that you have dynamic currency precision

- `value => 1.002431`
- `currency precision => 3`
- `result => 1.002

`CAST(Floor(your_float_value) AS VARCHAR) + '.' + REPLACE(STR(FLOOR((your_float_value FLOOR(your_float_value)) * power(10,cu_precision)), cu_precision), SPACE(1), '0')`