# how to get rid off decimals from sql results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am calculating total hours/minutes but i would like to get rid off the decimals and only show something like this 2.00 hours or 2.5 hours etc.  I am getting now something like this: 2.000000 and want only to limit to 2 decimals only.

```
 select DATEDIFF(minute, Min(FullDatetime), Max(FullDatetime)) / 60.0 as hours
  from  myTable
  where userid = 123
```

Comment: Formatting values for display is, as a rule, best left to your application code rather than being performed by the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by rounding but the easiest is to format for output using FORMAT().

```
 select FORMAT(DATEDIFF(minute, Min(FullDatetime), Max(FullDatetime)) / 60.0, 'N2') as hours
  from  myTable
  where userid = 123
```

Helpful original documentation: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634924.aspx)

Comment: this is the error i am getting: Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function.

Comment: my bad, saw tag is sql-server and not mysql... correcting now

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
 cast('values' as decimal(18,2))   --2 decimal place.

 select Cast((DATEDIFF(minute, Min(FullDatetime), Max(FullDatetime)) / 60.0 as hours)as decimal(18,2))
  from  myTable
  where userid = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options out there.
I prefer to use the following when no rounding is needed

```
FORMAT(value, 'N2')
```

[SQL - Rounding off to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places)

[how to get 2 digits after decimal point in tsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412231/how-to-get-2-digits-after-decimal-point-in-tsql)

Answer (score 0):

just use ROUND function such as : SELECT ROUND(columnName,decimals) from table

Answer (score 0):

You could use `STR` or `CONVERT` function:

```
DECLARE @v NUMERIC(19, 6)
SET     @v = 2.189189

SELECT STR(@v, 19, 2) AS Method1_Result_VARCHAR, CONVERT(NUMERIC(15, 2), @v) AS Method2_Result_NUMERIC
/*
Method1_Result_VARCHAR Method2_Result_NUMERIC
---------------------- ----------------------
               2.19    2.19
*/
```

Note: First argument of `STR` function has float type and this means that 1) SQL Server will convert this argument from `numeric` to `float` and 2) method 1 uses a non-deterministic expression.